# Image - Index out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, image, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem in java: I have a method in a class that paints an Image. 
EDIT: Changed || to &&'s, fixed the else, but now the image is red.
BTW: Assume the grid has been defined.

```
public BufferedImage scene() {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(250, 250, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    if (ready) {
        int tv=0;
        int tc=0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 250; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 250; y++) {
                int px = (int) ((x + r) / 16);
                int py = (int) (y / 16);
                if (px >= 0 && py >= 0 && px < width && py < height) {
                    image.setRGB(x, y, grid[px][py].image.getRGB(
                            (x + r) % 16, (y) % 16));
                } else {
                    image.setRGB(x, y, 0xFF0000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

But when I run the code I get:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
at general.Level.scene(Level.java:47)
at general.Game.paintComponent(Game.java:34)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1037)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5106)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4890)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:802)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:802)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:745)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:725)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:46)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1684)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Can you tell us the line that out of bounds exception is happening at?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the bug is produced by *your* code, by the file `Level.java` at line 47.

Comment: Did changing the `||` to `&&` fix the out-of-bounds exception? If so, it's really confusing to have the fixed code in your question now. If you have a separate problem then you need to create a new question.

Comment: *"Assume the grid has been defined."*  No, I won't.  Prove it with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: The question has been edited since I wrote this answer.*

This check seems to be wrong:

```
if (px >= 0 || py >= 0 || px < width || py < height)
```

You'll want logical AND (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`), otherwise it could be letting through invalid values of `px` or `py`. That's possibly what's causing your array index error (although you haven't shared enough code to be certain of that).